# Remove duplicates in a Range in Excel

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs to build add-ins in Excel Office 365 in mac environment.
I want to remove the duplicate rows in a range. Is there any way to achieve this ?
I could not find any API in range which allows me to remove the duplicate values.If there is any, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Not through the API at this moment -- it is part of the backlog for near-term implementation. No dates yet. Removal of duplicate values will have to be done client side for the moment, which is not very efficient.